# How to minimize $f(x) = \|Ax-b\|$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, optimization, maxima-minima

Solve the problem of minimizing $f(x) = ||Ax-b||$. Consider all the cases and interpret geometrically.

If we write

$$\|Ax-b\| = (a_{11}x_1 + \cdots + a_{1n}x_n - b_1)^2 + \cdots +  (a_{n1}x_1 + \cdots + a_{nn}x_n - b_1)^2$$

then

$$\frac{\partial \|Ax-b\|}{\partial x_j} = 2(a_{11}x_1 + \cdots + a_{1n}x_n - b_1)a_{1j} + \cdots +  (a_{n1}x_1 + \cdots + a_{nn}x_n - b_1)a_{nj}$$

If I try to do $\frac{\partial \|Ax-b\|}{\partial x_j} = 0$ I get nothing useful. For $x$ to be a minimizer, I have to have gradient $0$ and hessian positive definite. If we do the hessian just to see:

$$\frac{\partial^2 \|Ax-b\|}{\partial x_k\partial x_j} = 2a_{1k}a_{1j} + \cdots + 2a_{nk}a_{nj}$$

I see nothing useful here.

I think the geometric interpretation comes from the conditions for the gradient to be $0$ and the hessian to be $>0$, but I don't find these conditions useful.

Any ideas?

Comment: Notational point: you probably mean $\|Ax - b\|^2$ given the expansions you gave. The minimizers for both are the same.

Comment: Are you familiar with projections? What you want is just the projection of $b$ onto the range of $A$.

Comment: @cdipaolo right, it is $||Ax-b||$ in the exercise but I accidentaly tried to minimize $||Ax-b||^2$ but luckly they're the same, thanks

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I remember projection of vectors only. Your projection is a generalization of this concept?

Comment: One standard approach is to expand $\|Ax-b\|^2 = x^T A^T A x - 2b^T A x + b^Tb$, and set the derivative of this with respect to the _vector_ $x$ to zero. This will give you the result.

Comment: You might also try a few small cases like $n=2$ or $n=3$ to see what the right-hand side is in terms of $A$.

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs $b$ is  a vector and the range of $A$ is  a subspace.

Comment: Related: [Find $c$ to minimise $\sum_{k=1}^{m} (f(x_k)-c \cos(x_k))^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2848315) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand one of the comments of your question, the norm minimization problem you are considering is a projection problem. Note that projection of a vector $b$ onto a set $S$ is nothing but finding a point $x\in S$ such that the distance between $b$ and $x$ is minimized. Define the projection function as $\Pi_S:\mathbb R^m\to S$. The projection of $x$ onto $S$ is given by $\Pi_S(x)$:
$$
\Pi_s(x)=\arg\min_{y\in S}\|x-y\|.
$$
Therefore if $S$ is defined to be the range of $A$, that is 
$$
S=\{Ax: x\in\mathbb R^n\}.
$$
Then the problem of minimizing $\|b-Ax\|$, which is a least square problem, can be understood as projecting $b$ onto the rang of $A$, i.e., to find $\Pi_S(b)$.

The projection is given by a linear operator, say $P$. $P$ is symmetric and moreover by definition the projection of each vector $y\in S$ onto $S$ will be itself: $Py=y$. This means that $PA=A$. As an exercise try to see that the projection satisfies the intuitive idea that $Px-x$ should be orthogonal to each vector in $S$ (Hint: $A(I-P)=0$). See the figure below:
[image]

The projection matrix is unique (see why!) and therefore for each $b$ there is a unique point on the range of $A$ as the projection of $b$ namely $Pb$.

The projection into the range of $A$ can be found using [Moore-Penrose inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse) of $A$. The Moore-Penrose inverse of $A$, $A^\dagger$ satisfies among others:
$$
AA^\dagger A=A, A^\dagger AA^\dagger=A^\dagger.
$$
and $AA^\dagger$ is symmetric. With small efforts one can see that $P=AA^\dagger$. Therefore $z=AA^\dagger b$ gives you the projection of $b$ onto $S$. So we found the point $z$ in the range of $A$ minimizing the distance to $b$. But what about finding $x$ such that $Ax=z$? Well, in general there is no unique solution however we can see that:
$$
x=A^\dagger b\implies Ax=AA^\dagger b=z.
$$
Hence, $x=A^\dagger b$ is a solution. Moreover for $v$ in the kernel of $A$, $x+v$ is also a solution. The only way for unique solution is for $A$ to have only zero vector in the kernel.

Then how can we find $A^\dagger$? If $A^TA$ is invertible, $A^\dagger=(A^TA)^{-1}A^T$ as you could see in the other answers. Otherwise, there are other methods like using singular value decomposition to find the Moore-Penrose inverse.

Answer (score 7):

\begin{eqnarray*}
\left \lVert Ax-y\right\rVert^{2} &=& x^{T} A^{T} A x -2 y^{T} A x + y^{T} y
\end{eqnarray*}

Gradient w.r.t $x$ to $0$ translates to

\begin{eqnarray*}
\nabla_{x} \left \lVert Ax-y\right\rVert^{2} &=& 2 A^{T} A x - 2A^{T} y =0
\end{eqnarray*}

yields, the normal equations. The solution is (the well known Least Square).

\begin{equation*}
\hat{x}_{LS} = \left(A^{T} A \right)^{-1} A^{T} y
\end{equation*}

Geometrically, the least square solution can be viewed as an (orthogonal) projection of the observation $y$ onto the image of $A$.

Comment: how did you do $\begin{eqnarray*}
\left \lVert Ax-b\right\rVert^{2} &=& x^{T} A^{T} A x -2 y^{T} A x + y^{T} y
\end{eqnarray*}$?

Comment: I mean what are the steps to arrive at this?

Comment: I added a bounty. Would be nice if you could explain your decomposition

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs: $\|Ax-b\|^2 = (Ax-b)^T(Ax-b) = (x^TA^T-b^T)(Ax-b)$

Comment: Beware that $A^TA$ may be singular! (The linear system does always have a solution though.)

Answer (score 3):

**Alternative**:

In case you want to stick to $\lVert Ax - b \rVert = \mathrm{tr} \left[ \left(\left( Ax - b \right)^T \left( Ax - b \right) \right)^{\frac{1}{2}} \right]$, not the squared $\ell_2$ norm, i.e., $\lVert Ax - b \rVert^2$ (even though the final solution is same), here is an alternative.

We will utilize the following the identities

- Trace and Frobenius product relation $$\left\langle A, B \right\rangle={\rm tr}(A^TB)$$ or $$\left\langle A^T, B \right\rangle ={\rm tr}(AB)$$
- Cyclic property of Trace/Frobenius product 
  \begin{align}
  \left\langle A, B C \right\rangle 
   &= \left\langle AC^T, B \right\rangle  \\
   &= \left\langle B^T A, C \right\rangle \\
   &= {\text{etc.}} \cr
  \end{align}

We obtain the differential first, and then the gradient.

Moreover, you can utilize this trace differential result
\begin{align}
  d\,{\rm tr}(f(M)) 
  &= \left\langle f^\prime(M^T), \ dM \right\rangle ,\\
\end{align}
where $M = \left( Ax - b \right)^T \left( Ax - b \right)$ in the considered case and $f(\cdot) = \sqrt(\cdot)$.

So, 
\begin{align}
 d\, \lVert Ax - b \rVert &=  d\, \mathrm{tr} \left[ \left(\left( Ax - b \right)^T \left( Ax - b \right) \right)^{\frac{1}{2}} \right] \\
    &= \left\langle \frac {1} {2} \underbrace{\left[ \left(\left( Ax - b \right)^T \left( Ax - b \right) \right)^{-\frac{1}{2}} \right] }_{= \frac{1}{\lVert Ax - b \rVert}} , \ d\left[ \left(\left( Ax - b \right)^T \left( Ax - b \right) \right) \right] \right\rangle \\
    &= \left\langle \frac {1} {2 \lVert Ax - b \rVert}, \  dx^T A^T \left(Ax-b \right) + \left(Ax-b \right)^T A \ dx \right\rangle \\
    &= \left\langle \frac {1} {2 \lVert Ax - b \rVert}, \  2\left(Ax-b \right)^T A \ dx \right\rangle \\
    &= \left\langle \frac {A^T \left(Ax-b \right)} {\lVert Ax - b \rVert}, \    \ dx \right\rangle \\
\end{align}

Thus the derivative is 
$$ \eqalign {
 \frac { \partial} {\partial x}\lVert Ax - b \rVert &= \frac {A^T \left(Ax-b \right)} {\lVert Ax - b \rVert}  . \cr
} $$

Now, you can set the derivative to $0$ and the solution is the same as the above, i.e., 
\begin{align}
x = \left(A^T A \right)^{-1} A^T b \ .
\end{align}