# Computing the derivative of $\|Ax\|_2$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, normed-spaces, matrix-calculus, quadratic-forms

> Compute the following derivative (in matrix form) $$\frac{\partial\, \|Ax\|_2}{\partial x}$$ where $A$ is an arbitrary matrix and $x$ is a vector.

I think somebody said that the result is $2A^TAx$, but I cannot get even there. I have no idea how to develop this norm and derive it in matrix form.  Because if it were $$\frac{\partial \|x\|}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial x^Tx}{\partial x}=x$$ but with that matrix in the middle. I do not know how to solve that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The gradient of the square of the Euclidean norm of $Ax$, $\| Ax \|_{2}^{2}$, is $2A^{T}Ax$.

Comment: How do you define $\partial/(\partial x)$ where $x$ is a vector?

Comment: @BrianBorchers how do you derive to that result $2A^TAx$?

Comment: Compute the directional derivative. Then extract the gradient. Take a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2594270/339790).

Comment: Or alternatively take a look at this: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2890663/550103

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Euclidean norm ($p$ norm for $p=2$)
$$
\lVert y \rVert
= 
\left( \sum_i y_i^2 \right)^{1/2}
$$
for the $k$–th coordinate of the gradient by applying the chain rule several times we have 
$$
\begin{align}
\partial_k \lVert Ax \rVert
&= 
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_k} \left( \sum_i \left( \sum_j a_{ij}x_j \right)^2 \right)^{1/2} \\
&= 
\frac{1}{2 \lVert Ax\rVert}
\sum_i 2 \left( \sum_j a_{ij}x_j \right) a_{ij} \delta_{jk} \\
&= 
\frac{1}{\lVert Ax\rVert}
\sum_i a_{ik} \left( \sum_j a_{ij}x_j \right) \\
&= \frac{1}{\lVert Ax\rVert}\left( A^T A x \right)_k
\end{align}
$$
Note:Funny enough here I was able to recycle [another answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3167962/86776) from this morning.

Answer (score 4):

It is useful to introduce the Frobenius inner product as:

$$ A:B = \operatorname{tr}(A^TB)$$

with the following properties derivied from the underlying trace function

$$\eqalign{A:BC &= B^TA:C\cr &= AC^T:B\cr &= A^T:(BC)^T\cr &= BC:A \cr } $$

Then we work with differentials to find the gradient. Your problem becomes, with $u=Ax$

$$\eqalign{ f &= \|u\|_{F}^{2} = u:u \\
df &= 2u : du\\
   &= 2Ax : A dx\\
   &= 2A^TAx : dx}
$$

Thus

$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = 2 A^TAx$$

EDIT:

For $g = \|u\|_{2} $ this becomes:

$$\eqalign{ g&= f^{1/2} \\
dg &= \frac{1}{2} f^{-\frac{1}{2}} : df\\
dg &= \frac{1}{2} f^{-\frac{1}{2}} : 2u : du\\
&=f^{-\frac{1}{2}} u : du\\
&=\frac{1}{||Ax||} Ax : Adx\\
&=\frac{1}{||Ax||} A^TAx : dx\\
}$$

$$\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}= \frac{1}{||Ax||}A^T A x$$

Comment: Nice answer!  Alienflow also asked for $\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}$ where $g(x) = ||A x ||$.  Could you add  $\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}= \frac1{||Ax||}A^T A x$ to your answer?